# Insert method call to a certain place of the InitializeComponent

Tags: c#, winforms, codedom

I am trying to extend default content of the InitializeComponent method.
I would like several method calls to be added there.

Problem is - I need this calls to be located in specific places of the InitializeComponent method.

For example, I would like to call my method after each field initialization:

```
    this.ctrl1 = new UserControl();
    MyMethod(); // <---- call of my method
    this.ctrl2 = new UserControl();
    MyMethod(); // <---- call of my method
    this.SuspendLayout();
    .................................
```

I was trying to change a little bit default behaviour of the `CodeDomSerializer`. My idea was to find each `CodeFieldReferenceExpression` and to add `CodeMethodReferenceExpression` right after it.

```
public class CodeDomSerializerEx : CodeDomSerializer
{
    public override object Serialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, object value)
    {
        for (int index = 0; manager.Context[index] != null; index++)
        {
            StatementContext context = manager.Context[index] as StatementContext;
            if (context != null)
            {
                foreach (DictionaryEntry dictionaryEntry in context.StatementCollection)
                {
                    CodeStatementCollection _statements = dictionaryEntry.Value as CodeStatementCollection;
                    if(_statements != null)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < _statements.Count; i++)
                        {
                            CodeAssignStatement assign = _statements[i] as CodeAssignStatement;
                            if (assign != null)
                            {
                                CodeFieldReferenceExpression field = assign.Left as CodeFieldReferenceExpression;
                                if (field != null)
                                {
                                    CodeMethodReferenceExpression _ref = new CodeMethodReferenceExpression(
                                        new CodeThisReferenceExpression(),
                                        "MyMethod");
                                    CodeMethodInvokeExpression save = new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(_ref, new CodeExpression[0]);
                                    CodeExpressionStatement newSt = new CodeExpressionStatement(save);
                                    _statements.Insert(i, newSt);
                                    i += 1;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        CodeDomSerializer serializer = (CodeDomSerializer)manager.GetSerializer(typeof(UserControl).BaseType, typeof(CodeDomSerializer));
        object return_value = serializer.Serialize(manager, value);

        return return_value;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this is what I am getting as a result

```
    this.ctrl1 = new UserControl();
    this.ctrl2 = new UserControl();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    MyMethod(); // <---- call of my method
    .................................
```

Someone does reorganization of CodeDom expressions to make InitializeComponent method look like this:

1. fields initialization
2. SuspendLayout
3. set properties for the initialized fields
4. add fields to Controls collection
5. set properties for the container
6. ResumeLayout

I there a way to change that?